# Tkinter background colour issue

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

I have a script that has a Tkinter module in it that i would like to change the background color in 3min intervals e.g green for 3mins then orange then red.
I have the code to display the green but can't get it to change.

When I make a function in my code it gets a few different errors including 
'root not defined, global name "root" no defined' although it is.

Also on a side note kill the Tk display after 15 mins so once all 3 colours have been though.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import BasePlugin
import os, sys
import time
from Tkinter import *

def Orange (*args,**kwargs):
    root.config(background="Orange")
def Red(*args,**kwargs):
    root.config(background="Red")

class dis(BasePlugin):
       def execute(self, msg, unit, address, when, printer, print_copies):
        mseg = str('%s - %s' % (msg, unit))
        root = Tk()
        root.title('label')
        txt = Label(root, font= 'times 20 bold', bg='Green')
        txt.config(text= mseg)
        txt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=0)
        root.after(10,Orange)
        root.after(10,Red)

        root.mainloop(0)

PLUGIN = dis
```

I have also tried

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import BasePlugin
import os, sys
import time
from Tkinter import *

def Orange (*args,**kwargs):
    txt.config(background="Orange")
def Red(*args,**kwargs):
    txt.config(background="Red")

class dis(BasePlugin):
       def execute(self, msg, unit, address, when, printer, print_copies):
        mseg = str('%s - %s' % (msg, unit))
        root = Tk()
        root.title('label')
        txt = Label(root, font= 'times 20 bold', bg='Green')
        txt.config(text= mseg)
        txt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=0)
        txt.after(10,Orange)
        txt.after(10,Red)

        root.mainloop(0)

PLUGIN = dis
```

If I place `root = Tk()` anywhere else I get a small gray TK box that I don't want.

P.S I know that it's set to 10 seconds that's only so I can test it

Comment: it's currently set to 10 _milliseconds_, not 10 _seconds_. The argument to `after` is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) four problems with your code, but that's difficult to tell, since you are not showing us all the details. In particular, you never seem to call `execute`, but I'll assume that this happens somewhere else, maybe via the super class...

- `root` is defined inside `execute`, thus to access it in your callback functions, you either have to make it global, or a member of the `dis` instance, or put the callback functions *inside* execute
- the delay in `after` is in milliseconds, so using `10` the colours will switch instantaneously, which is probably not the best setup for testing
- as it stands, both `after` callbacks are executed at the exact same time; either put one at the end of the other callback function, or use different times
- you change the background of the `root` panel, while in fact you want to change the background of the `txt` Label

For example, you could try like this (minimal stand-alone example)

```
class dis:
    def execute(self):
        def orange():
            txt.config(bg="Orange")
            root.after(2000, red)
        def red():
            txt.config(bg="Red")
            root.after(2000, kill)
        def kill():
            root.destroy()
        root = Tk()
        txt = Label(root, text="some text", font='times 20 bold', bg='Green')
        txt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=0)
        root.after(2000, orange)
        root.mainloop()
dis().execute()
```

Or shorter, just using a bunch of `lambda`:

```
class dis:
    def execute(self):
        root = Tk()
        txt = Label(root, text="some text", font='times 20 bold', bg='Green')
        txt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=0)
        root.after(2000, lambda: txt.config(bg="Orange"))
        root.after(4000, lambda: txt.config(bg="Red"))
        root.after(6000, root.destroy)
        root.mainloop()
dis().execute()
```

Comment: Used top example but removed the dis().execute() and added (self, msg, unit, address, when, printer, print_copies): to def execute up the top. THANKS for the HELP

Answer (score 1):

Or a little more generic using a list

```
class dis():
    def __init__(self):
        mseg = ("test message")
        self.color_list=["green", "orange", "red"]
        self.ctr=0
        root = Tk()
        root.title('label')
        self.txt = Label(root, font= 'times 20 bold', width=20)
        self.txt.config(text= mseg)
        self.txt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=0)
        self.change_color()

        root.mainloop()

    def change_color(self):
        self.txt.config(background=self.color_list[self.ctr])
        self.ctr += 1
        if self.ctr > 2:
           self.ctr=0
        self.txt.after(500, self.change_color)

PLUGIN = dis()
```